# Android dynamic viewpager and tablayout from JSON data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am following this tutorial https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-tablayout-with-many-tabs-kotlin/

i am modify method to add fragment, but i need jump to specific tab in tablayout. this tutorial not return the tab position (page) correctly and every jump (lets say tab 5), always load  every tab (0,1,2,3,4,5) not straight to tab 5, every tab need to take data from server so its take to much time for fetching data in all tab.

Listing Class

```
class Listing : AppCompatActivity() {

// From server
var latitude = ""
var longitude = ""
var category:Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing)

    getCategory()
}

fun getCategory(){
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val dialogView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog,null)
    builder.setView(dialogView)
    builder.setCancelable(false)
    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()

    var rq: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    var sr = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, user_info.get_category, Response.Listener { response ->
        //========================================================================================= data from server
        Handler().postDelayed({dialog.dismiss()},0)
        Log.i("AIM", response.toString())

        val pageAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        var jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
        var data:JSONObject = jsonObject["data"] as JSONObject
        var jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("vendor_type")

        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
            var jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)

            var id  = jo["id"].toString()
            var nama = jo["nama"].toString()

            pageAdapter.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(i), nama)
            user_info.nama_category.add(i,nama)
            Log.d("aim","Fragment created")
        }

        viewpager_main.adapter = pageAdapter
        tabs_main.setupWithViewPager(viewpager_main)


        if (category != 0){
            var fix = category - 1
            viewpager_main.setCurrentItem(fix, false)
        }


    }, Response.ErrorListener { response ->
        //========================================================================================= error handling
        Handler().postDelayed({dialog.dismiss()},0)

        var networkResponse = response.networkResponse
        if (networkResponse == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tidak terhubung dengan server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }) {        }
    sr.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
            10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    )
    rq.add(sr)
  }
}
```

Fragment

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

private val vendorData = mutableListOf<vendor_model>()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    val page = getArguments()!!.getInt(PAGE_NUM)


    Log.d("aim", "page : $page")

    getVendor(page)

    return view
}

companion object {
    val PAGE_NUM = "PAGE_NUM"
    fun newInstance(page: Int): FirstFragment {
        val fragment = FirstFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putInt(PAGE_NUM, page)
        fragment.setArguments(args)
        return fragment
    }
}

fun getVendor(page: Int) {
    val builder = activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it) }
    val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog,null)
    builder?.setView(dialogView)
    builder?.setCancelable(false)
    val dialog = builder?.create()
    dialog?.show()

    var category = page + 1
    Log.d("aim", "category : $category")


    var rq: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
    var sr = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, Response.Listener { response ->
        Handler().postDelayed({dialog?.dismiss()},0)
        Log.i("AIM", response.toString())

        var jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
        var jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list")

        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
            var jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)

            var jarak: String
            if (jo.isNull("distance")) {
                jarak = "Unknown"
            }else  jarak = jo["distance"].toString() + " Km"


            var id  = jo["id_vendor"].toString()
            var nama = jo["nama"].toString()
            //var jarak = jo["distance"].toString()
            var rating = jo["rating"].toString()
            var status = jo["is_open"].toString()
            var img = jo["file_logo"].toString()
            var category = jo["vendor_type"].toString()

            val mItem = vendor_model(id, nama, "$jarak", rating, status, img, category)
            vendorData.add(mItem)
        }

        // ============ recycler_nearme ============
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL,false)
        val vendorAdapter = vendor_adapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = vendorAdapter
        vendorAdapter.setList(vendorData)
        vendorData.clear()

    }, Response.ErrorListener { response ->
        Handler().postDelayed({dialog?.dismiss()},0)
        //========================================================================================= error handling

        Toast.makeText(activity, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        var networkResponse = response.networkResponse

        if (networkResponse == null){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Tidak terhubung dengan server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else {
            var code = networkResponse.statusCode
            var err = networkResponse.data
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error : $code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Log.i("AIM", err.toString())
        }

    }) {
        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String,String> {
            var map = HashMap<String, String>()

            map.put("text"          , "")
            map.put("tags"          , "")
            map.put("take"          , "10")
            map.put("skip"          , "0")
            map.put("sort_by"       , "asc")
            map.put("language"      , "[]")

            map.put("type"          , "")
            map.put("category"      , "[$category]")
            map.put("grade"         , "[]")

            map.put("nearme"        , "0")
            map.put("distance"      , "")
            map.put("location"      , "")
            map.put("latitude"      , "")
            map.put("longitude"     , "")

            map.put("open_now"      , "")
            map.put("price_min"     , "")
            map.put("price_max"     , "")

            map.put("rating"        , "")
            map.put("rating_max"    , "")
            map.put("rating_min"    , "")
            map.put("ratings"       , "[]")
            map.put("subject"       , "")


            return map
        }
    }
    sr.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
            3000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    )
    rq.add(sr)
    Log.i("aim", sr.body.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()))
  }
}
```

Adapter

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager): FragmentPagerAdapter(fm){

  private val tabNames: ArrayList<String>
  private val fragments: ArrayList<Fragment>

  init {
    tabNames = ArrayList()
    fragments = ArrayList()
  }

  fun add(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
    tabNames.add(title)
    fragments.add(fragment)
  }

  override fun getCount(): Int {
    return fragments.size
  }

  override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragments[position]
  }

  override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
    return tabNames[position]
  }
}
```

thank you for your answer, really apreciated

Comment: Yours `viewpager_main.setCurrentItem(4)` does not work?

Comment: Its working, but load every tab from 0 until 4 (0,1,2,3,4) not straight to 4, taking time so much. @Boken

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional parameter (second one as `false`):

```
viewpager_main.setCurrentItem(4, false)
```

> Set `true` to smoothly scroll to the new item,
>
> Set `false` to do transition immediately

Comment: I have tried both "viewpager_main.setCurrentItem(fix, false)", the results are same. the fragment always run one by one. now i will try with static fragment  (one for each category). but the problem is when app get update for additional category need create fragment again.